# New versions of Android app not showing up on Play Store, even after weeks

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

My company has an Android app published on the Play Store since 2018. We never had any problem with the app's distribution, however since July 2020 new versions submitted and released with full rollout do not appear on the Play Store's web page or Android app - they only show an older version, published on June 2020.

We are sure that this is not a matter of caching on our end, as it is consistent across devices and platforms.

Initially, we noted that the `Pre-launch report` page of the Developer Console showed a few errors for these newer builds and thought that because of them the system would not release the updates, so we fixed the errors. It didn't work.

We also used to use fastlane for preparing the app's APK and uploading it, so we tried preparing  the APK using Android Studio's `Generate Signed APK` option and uploading it manually. It also didn't work.

Our app deals with mature themes (partner swapping), but we take very good care for it to be as safe as possible. The Google Play's Developer Console shows no warning or error message for the app, so we doubt this could be the reason.

New beta and internal versions appear to beta and internal testers, but when upgraded to production, they go back to the old version from June.

No changes were made to `minSdkVersion` or `targetSdkVersion`.

Comment: What do you see when you open your app's page in Google Play Developer Console? Do you see the text "All updates are live", or "Processing update"?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about this field, I had forgotten about it. Right now, though, it is Processing update, because I just uploaded a new version, a test of sorts. Will wait a few  hours and check it again.